# Create function with parameters in R

Tags: r, function, vector, parameters

I create a function with parameters.

```
arma_function<-function(y,param){
    param<-c("c","phi","theta")
    as.numeric(factor(param))
    T<-seq(1:length(y))
    mu[1]<-param[["c"]]/(1-param[["theta"]])
    eps[1]<-y[1]-mu[1]  
    for (t in 2:lengt(T)){
      mu[t]<-param[["c"]]+param[["phi"]]*y[t-1]+param[["theta"]]*eps[t-1]
      eps[t]<-y[t]-mu[t]
    return(c(mu[t],eps[t]))
    }
}
```

Read of library datasets to load.

```
library(datasets)
```

Create variables with values.

```
y <- as.numeric(Nile)
param <- c(mean(y)*(1-0.9), 0.9, -0.5)

Trying reading the last values in the function but I cant get. 
arma <- arma_function(y, param)
```

I get the next problem:

```
Error in param[["c"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How can I fix?

Comment: Why exactly are you overwriting param as your first step in the function? It won't matter what you input for param since you're just replacing it with your character vector right away. Also you misspelled `length` in your for loop declaration.

Comment: Because I want to replacing this variable y and param in the function. Thanks, I forgot the "h" in the word length.

Comment: Aside from not getting an error, what is your expected result?

Comment: I want to y and param variables get in arma_function. Thanks

Comment: And what should be the result of the function? Reason I ask is that I fixed the syntax errors but I do not believe that the function is already doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: The function must to:

- Create a vector with the data (from y1 to yT),
- Another vector with next parameters (c, phi, theta)

With these inputs, the function has to return me:
- a vector mu: with this formula → mu [t] = c + phi * y [t-1] + theta * eps [t-1]
- and an eps vector: with this formula → eps [t] = y [t] -mu [t]